# Getting strings between two specific occurrences of specific characters in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the following code. How can I extract/get strings between to specific numbers of characters in an string like
`lorem1-lorem9-lorem3-lorem8-lorem1-lorem11-one-two-three-lorem22-lorem55.png`?

What I need is:

> one-two-three

I am able to remove things after the `9` occurrence of the `-` but not sure how to remove things before the `6` occurrence of `-` as well

```js
var str = "lorem1-lorem9-lorem3-lorem8-lorem1-lorem11-one-two-three-lorem22-lorem55.png"
console.log(str.split("-", 9).join("-"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array.prototype.splice` can be used to split an array.

```js
var str = "lorem1-lorem9-lorem3-lorem8-lorem1-lorem11-one-two-three-lorem22-lorem55.png"

let out = str.split("-", 9).splice(6).join("-")

console.log(out);
```